data type has no default operator class for access method "gist"
I have a table with a column with data type pcpatch from pgpointcloud.
When I try to create spatial index on it:
CREATE INDEX geom_data_idx ON geom_data USING gist (geom_data);

This gives me error:
data type pcpatch has no default operator class for access method "gist"

I am on postgres 16.
What am I missing in my setup?

I think you can only index a geometry that corresponds to the patch, not the patch itself. Like so: CREATE INDEX ON patches USING GIST(PC_EnvelopeGeometry(patch));. That requires postgis and pointcloud_ postgis extensions. Your error message suggests geom_data is a pcpatch, not a geometry type, which seems a bit misleading. You can either make an expression index like in the example above, or set up a generated column and index that.
